# Angular reactive form validators with state holding?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a case when user is on a wizard form and it is possible to get back to previous form step. I have there a validation of some value which is executed by making a http request to backend validation app.

When user will back to this step I don't want to force making this request again, because it is already validated. Is it possible to make this by validators (holding state of current validation) or it is a better idea to place this kind of validation inside a component / directive.

Comment: please post code of what you have tried so far.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: "Not all questions benefit from including code, but if your problem is with code you've written, you should include some" - like in this case :). There is too much code to make from it a good example. I just need validation if my lead is good

Comment: btw. did you even read the question? I doubt that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create and store new flag `validated` in Service or Local Storage or in store (if you use NgRx or Akita). When the user data is validated in one step, just mark the flag as `true`. When user reloads the page or comes back to the step, show the message based on the flag.

Comment: Sorry for late answer I didn't get notification about this post. I did almost exactly like you wrote. I have one point of truth in one service for my form, which is service with all form controls, and there in one form group I have field which I need to validate and "helper field" which stores status of validation, it works ideally with attached validatiors to them. When user change "validated field", on result field is reseted.